# Responsive links in HTML Email directing customers to mobile site or desktop site

Tags: mobile, html-email, browser-detection

We recently had a mobile site built which was great but when we send out our html emails I'm having to use media queries on the links to send customers to the desktop site or mobile site  as the URLs are different Eg. m.mobilesite.com and www.desktopsite.com.

I'd like to use something like 'detectmobilebrowsers.com' so I can do away with the media queries and have one link which is built up of both the mobile and desktop links. The setup advice on this site is not very helpful.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't like the sound of that. You cannot guarantee that the mail/webmail client will be able to support "responsive links", regardless of the device that the user is viewing it on. Hence, you could very well be pointing users to the wrong device specific site.

What I would do, is point all of your email links to the main site version. At that point, you should have some form of device detection in place on your server. Your site logic should be able to forward the user on to the correct site specific page (e.g. mobile visitor sent to mobile version of same page, desktop user not redirected).

If you don't any redirection logic in place (you really should, [read this](http://www.9xb.com/blog-2012-08-6-common-pitfalls-when-deploying-a-mobile-site-and-how-they-can-be-avoided/)), basically this is what you're looking to achieve:

[http://www.9xb.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/mobile-deployment-small.png](http://www.9xb.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/mobile-deployment-large.png)

If you're not following the [rules laid out by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details) regarding redirects and canonical link tags, you may find yourself in trouble at some point.

If this is all a bit beyond your technical ability, I'd suggest you speak with whoever built your mobile site as this isn't for the faint hearted.